# Pointer char function not running the second time

Tags: c

I have written this function which reads a file, compares a string to each line and if the line contains the string, it return it.

```
    char* FileSearch2 (char* File_Name , char* String) { 
        FILE * T = fopen(File_Name, "rt");
        char* Line = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char*) * 1024);
        strcat(String,"\t");
        if (T) {
            while (fgets(Line,1024,T)) {
                if (strstr(Line, String) != NULL) {
                    fclose(T);
                    return Line;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(T);
        return "0";
    }
```

The problem is that, the second time I run this function it always returns "0".

For example

```
char* FirstRun = FileSearch2 ("File.txt", Value); // Assuming the value is "Hello", it returns the line
```

Now

```
char* SecondtRun = FileSearch2 ("File.txt", Value); // Assuming the value is "Hello", it returns "0"
```

I would like to know what exactly I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe unrelated questions: 1) why you allocate 128 characters buffer but you ask to read up to 1024? 2) Why you return a _static_ constant to caller function??? Will they free that memory like the other case? 3) Why you cast malloc return value? 4) Why do you change a parameter? Especially if it's a constant like in your example...what will happen to memory???

Comment: Don't cast result of malloc in c

Comment: @Adriano, Sorry typing error

Comment: You never free the memory you allocate to `char* Line`

Comment: Please, free your memory when done with it too. You are requesting lots of 1024 char chunks that never seem to be released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a few serious errors.

For instance, your `malloc()` logic is all wrong.

You seem to want to allocate room for a line of 1024 characters, but you do this:

```
char* Line = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char*) * 128);
```

it should just be:

```
char *Line = malloc(1024);
```

[Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), and the business with `sizeof(char *)` is just plain wrong and confused.

Then you fail to `free()` the line if the line is not found, which is another problem.

Your code also changes the caller's data by calling `strcat()`, which means that if you call it with e.g. a string literal (as your example implies) it's totally undefined behavior what's going to happen. You should re-think that part with the `'\t'`-appending, it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: It's fine on a 64-bit system, (well, not really:).

Comment: Thank you unwind, I think I understood what's the problem, I'll accept your answer

Comment: This answer is useful, but it's unlikely to solve the problem as reported. See my answer for a hint on that!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I expect it's because you function FileSearch modifies `String` by appending a tab character to it. So the second time through, you're looking for a string with two tabs at the end.

You should make a copy of `String`, append the tab to the copy, and free the copy at the end.

```
char *copy = strdup(String);

strcat(copy,"\t");
if (T) {
    while (fgets(Line,1024,T)) {
        if (strstr(Line, copy) != NULL) {
            fclose(T);
            free(copy);
            return Line;
```

And, as @unwind says, you need to free `Line` (and `copy`) if the string isn't found, too.

Comment: Thank you very much Roddy indeed